# ChartJS failed to create chart : can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, initialization

I try to initialize a chart with chartJS library but it fails at the initialization.

Here the error from core.controller.js (the chartJS library) :

```
if (!context || !canvas) {
      // The given item is not a compatible context2d element, let's return before finalizing
      // the chart initialization but after setting basic chart / controller properties that
      // can help to figure out that the chart is not valid (e.g chart.canvas !== null);
      // https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2807
      console.error("Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item");
      return;
    }
```

I tried to implement some logs to debug but no one is showing so I guess the initialization should be good...

Here my code :

twig html :

```
<canvas id="chartCanvas18" height="450" style="max-height: 450px"></canvas>
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/utils/helpers/testgraph.helpers.js') }}"></script> {# The JS script #}
{% endblock %}
```

testgraph.helpers.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    const chartManager = new ChartManager(chartConfig, idToLabelAndStyles);
    const dataFetcher = new DataFetcher();

    let canvas = document.getElementById("chartCanvas18");
    if (!canvas) {
        console.error('Canvas element with id "chartCanvas" not found.');
        return;
    }

    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (!ctx) {
        console.error('Unable to get 2D context from canvas element.');
        return;
    }

    // Initialize and update the chart
    chartManager.initializeChart("line");

    const startdate = "2020-06-01";
    const enddate = "2020-06-07";

    const selectDate = $('#daterange-btn')
    const selectCourbe = $('#graph-courbe')
    const selectRegr = $('#graph-regrouppement')
    const selectCompt = $('#graph-compteur')

    dataFetcher.getDatas(selectRegr.val(), selectCompt.val(), startdate, enddate)
        .then(data => chartManager.updateChart(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
})


class ChartManager {
    constructor(initialConfig, idToLabelAndStyles) {
        this.config = initialConfig;
        this.idToLabelAndStyles = idToLabelAndStyles;
        this.chart = null;
    }

    initializeChart(type) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('chartCanvas18');
        if (!canvas) {
            console.error('Canvas element with id "chartCanvas18" not found.');
            return;
        }

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!ctx) {
            console.error('Unable to get 2D context from canvas element.');
            return;
        }

        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type,
            data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [],
            },
            options: this.config.options,
        });
    }

    updateChart(data) {
        if (!this.chart) {
            console.error('Chart not initialized.');
            return;
        }

        if (!data || typeof data !== 'object' || !Array.isArray(data.axis) || !Array.isArray(data.values)) {
            console.error('Invalid data format.');
            return;
        }

        // Destroy the old chart before creating a new one
        this.chart.destroy();

        // Create a new chart with the updated data
        this.chart = new Chart(this.chart.ctx, {
            type: this.chart.config.type,
            data: {
                labels: data.axis,
                datasets: data.values.map(({ id, values }) => {
                    const labelAndStyles = this.idToLabelAndStyles[id];
                    if (!labelAndStyles) {
                        console.error(`No label and styles found for id "${id}".`);
                        return null;
                    }

                    return {
                        label: labelAndStyles.label,
                        data: values,
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: labelAndStyles.borderColor,
                        backgroundColor: labelAndStyles.backgroundColor,
                    };
                }).filter(dataset => dataset !== null),
            },
            options: this.chart.config.options,
        });
    }
}

const chartConfig = {
    type: "line",
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tension: 0.4,
        scales: {},
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
};

const idToLabelAndStyles = {
    0: {
        label: "All",
        borderColor: "yellow",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
    },
    1: {
        label: "PI",
        borderColor: "cyan",
        backgroundColor: "cyan",
    },
    2: {
        label: "EC",
        borderColor: "red",
        backgroundColor: "red",
    },
    3: {
        label: "CA",
        borderColor: "yellow",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
    },
};
```

Comment: All the examples I can see in the docs, pass the reference to an HTML element as first parameter of the constructor. Why are you passing a context instead? Is it _supposed_ to work that way?

Comment: In the docs I seen it passed an context element as first parameter. The context element is obtained from the canvas html element. 
Documentation :
new Chart(ctx, {
    // this is the string the constructor was registered at, ie Chart.controllers.MyType
    type: 'MyType',
    data: data,
    options: options
});

Comment: Only page where Google finds that code with that specific comments, appears to be https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html And in that location, it doesn't even show where `ctx` comes from.

Comment: Yes I seen here it pass the html element : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/
But tried to changed by the html element and nothing changed.
I think you can pass the html element or directly the context as first parameter

Comment: Is it perhaps this line, that is actually triggering the error? `this.chart = new Chart(this.chart.ctx, {` - not sure if `this.chart.ctx` still exists, when you did `this.chart.destroy();` before?

Comment: Okay I think you are correct !
I tried this after destroy the chart :

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // Re-acquire the context from the canvas
    if (!ctx) {
        console.error('Unable to get 2D context from canvas element.');
        return;
    }

but get 'canvas is not defined' I need change somethings I guess

Comment: `canvas` is local to the scope of your `initializeChart` method.

Comment: Yes I was thinking to add it in the constructor so ?
constructor(initialConfig, idToLabelAndStyles) {
        this.config = initialConfig;
        this.idToLabelAndStyles = idToLabelAndStyles;
        this.chart = null;
        this.canvas = null; // Add here
    }

Comment: So now I use the canvas from the constructor to keep it available ! It works good, thank you